# Add span or some tag to other language text in a phrase

Tags: php, unicode, character, unicode-string

In a PHP variable a mixed language context is present. An example is below:

```
$variable="This is sample text I am storing in the variable. இதன் கூடவே மற்ற மொழி எழுத்துக்களும் உள்ளன"
```

So the variable `$variable` contains both English and other language (Tamil in the above example).

Now I need to add a tag with class something enclosing the Tamil text such as:

```
$variable="This is sample text I am storing in the variable. <span class='tamil'>இதன் கூடவே மற்ற மொழி எழுத்துக்களும் உள்ளன</span>"
```

How to omit the English letters and punctuation symbols and add `<span>` to other language sentence completely or paragraph?

Comment: From what I understand of your question, it is not about separating __languages__ but __character sets__, which is quite different (and much easier).

Comment: What are you trying to do? is this for web standards compliancy?

Comment: The fact is English have 26 letters so that I can use some logic with `A-Za-z`. But this other language have 247 letters and I cannot also use `preg_match`.

Comment: @Filype: Sometimes I need to display the output of `$variable`. I need to add some styling rules for English and Other language text separately.

Comment: @CroResistor it does not have to be done with regex... The question is: do you want to be able to separate languages with similar characters (say English and German)? If yes, it is about languages. If not, it is about characters.

Comment: Na. I want to separate English text and Tamil/Hindi text.

Comment: From the comments, it seems that you want to use different fonts for different languages, but the question does not say this or even allude to it. You should formulate the question as relating to fonts, if that is really what you regard as a problem. But consider first that in general the same font should be used for all text, and the choice of font should be based on the character requirements of all characters involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Filype mentioned, we can use the unicode ranges for this.

This should match even in cases like 'English' -> 'Tamil' -> 'English' -> 'Tamil'.  Though it'll wrap extra spaces into the span.

```
/**
 * @param String $str Input UTF-8 encoded string.
 */
function encapsulate_tamil($str)
{
   return preg_replace('/[\x{0B80}-\x{0BFF}][\x{0B80}-\x{0BFF}\s]*/u',
      '<span class=\'tamil\'>$0</span>', $str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a unicode range that you can use to create a regex, this will help you find tamil chars in your text: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0B80.pdf

```
[\u0B80-\u0BFA-]*
```

I have put together a playground for this example so that you can improve it to do what you need to do.

http://regex101.com/r/wT8hP4

The following is not gold plated code, but hope it can get you started.

```
<?php

$variable="This is sample text I am storing in the variable. இதன் கூடவே மற்ற மொழி எழுத்துக்களும் உள்ளன";

echo add_tamil_class($variable);

/**
 * Adds a HTML Span tag around tamil text using regex
 */
function add_tamil_class($text) {

    preg_match_all("/[\x{0B80}-\x{0BFA}]+/u", $text, $matches);

    $tamilSentence = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
    return str_replace(
        $tamilSentence,
        "<span class='tamil'>".$tamilSentence."</span>",
        $text
        );
}
```

Comment: Well! This works perfect for sentence like this `தமிழ் எழுத்து English text`". But it does not add the `<span>` for text with mixed occurrences say `தமிழ் English எழுத்து text". It simply omits I guess.

Comment: yes, see EPB answer for the right way of doing it! :)

Comment: Great! So with your permission, I am accepting his answer :) THough thanks you :)